# Program that cannot acess input from a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception

I have a program that scans a file and then closes the file.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class FileTester{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     File test = new File("MyDatta.in.txt");
     Scanner sf = new Scanner(test);
       sf.close();
 }
}
```

When I run the program I get an error message like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: MyDatta.in.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
at FileTester.main(FileTester.java:6)
```

I have a mac that runs on Mac OS. I have reason to believe it has to do with the pathway to my file which is in documents. I know in windows one would use `C:\folder name\file` to scan it but I just don't know with Mac and I cannot find it anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put this as the file path:

```
~/Documents/MyDatta.in.txt
```

to tell java that your file is in documents. The `~` is your home folder.

Comment: It still throws the same error but thanks, I didn't know that. :)

Answer (score 1):

From Java documentation for FileInputStream: "If the named file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading then a FileNotFoundException is thrown."

Maybe file is used by another program?